# Ruby - pass variable to eval method

Tags: ruby, function, metaprogramming, eval, idioms

I have a variable which reference a method, I call the method with the eval keyword

```
a_test = "myvariable"
eval a_test


def myvariable
(...)
end
```

I would like to pass a variable to method, such as

```
def myvariable(var1)
(...)
end
```

Is anyone familiar with any "idiom" way of accomplishing this. Doing something like

```
eval a_test "string_test"
```

will naturally fail since a lookup will be done by the interpreter for a function called "a_test"

Comment: try this `eval "#{a_test}('string_test')"`

Comment: Just to make it clean: `myvariable` in this case **is not** a variable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work for you

```
def myvariable(foo)
  return "hello #{foo}"
end
a_test = "myvariable"

eval "puts #{a_test}('world')"

#=> hello world
```

---

In ruby though, it would be more appropriate to do something like this

```
def myvariable(foo)
  return "hello #{foo}"
end
a_test = "myvariable"

puts send(a_test, 'world')

#=> hello world
```

Read more about [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send)